# How to query ipython (jupyterlab?) kernel from javascript in the notebook?

Tags: ipython, jupyter

You can write some html and js and display things in the notebook but what is the standard way of querying the "backend" ... i.e. sending requests to the python process driving the notebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Jupyter messaging protocol:
https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/stable/messaging.html

Comment: Looks broadly sufficient but will leave it open to see if anyone wants to put minimal example of some html/js querying the kernel either through messaging or by spinning up a webserver.

Comment: Also see this: https://jupyter-kernel-gateway.readthedocs.io/en/latest/